# Is there an execute api of read in Freeswitch?

Tags: freeswitch

I have gone thru the Freeswitch API document and what I am looking for is a javascript API which is to replace the read action in my dialplan.
If I do not use javascript, the code will be like below:

```
<action application="read" data="4 4 /usr/share/freeswitch/sounds/en/us/callie/conference/8000/pin-number.wav conference_pin_input 10000 #" />
```

I have found other APIs, like

```
<action application="hangup">
```

in javascript is session.hangup() and so on.

Currently I have gone thru the two documents which are https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Session+Execute and https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/JavaScript+API+Reference, but I think the document is quite poor, lots of things that we want need to read the source code. Can I please ask whether there is a javascript API to read the user input from dtmf?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can still use that application from session.execute():

```
session.execute('read', '4 4 /usr/share/freeswitch/sounds/en/us/callie/conference/8000/pin-number.wav conference_pin_input 10000 #');
```